# getting numeric values from array which also contains null

Tags: javascript

I am applying for-each loop in an object having 3 arrays;

```
this.chart.ref.series.forEach(element=> {
   ...
});
```

In element, every time one series object come.
If I look at `element.options.data`, I'm getting an array like this.

```
[140,290,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

I have rest of the arrays in same type that I will get in my for-each element, now my requirement is to add the last values and starting values of every array that is numeric (not null) and store it in two separate variables like `startingAccountValues` and `endingAccountValues`.

For example, three arrays I have like

```
[140,290,null,null,null,null,null,null],
[110,130,120,140,null,null,null,null],
[270,390,230,null,null,null,null,null]
```

So as the result I want something like

`startingAccountValues = 520` (140+110+270)
`endingAccountValues = 660` (290+140+230)

Answer (score 0):

Map the array to the required inner property, filter out the `null` values and then add the first and the last values of each array to your results.

```
let startingAccountValues = 0;
let endingAccountValues  = 0;

this.chart.ref.series
  .map(x => x.options.data)
  .filter(x => x !== null)
  .map(x => {
    startingAccountValues += x[0];
    endingAccountValues += x[x.length - 1]; 
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf(null)-1` for the sum of `endingAccountValues` in your code like the code below. Don't consider this as a complete code as you have different data structure for the array `series`. You need to use this code accordingly to your data structure for `series`. The core logic will be same as in `series.forEach`

```js
var series = [
  [140,290,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [110,130,120,140,null,null,null,null],
  [270,390,230,null,null,null,null,null]
];
var startingAccountValues = 0 ,endingAccountValues = 0;

series.forEach((element)=>{
  startingAccountValues += element[0];
  endingAccountValues += element[element.indexOf(null)-1];
});

console.log('startingAccountValues is ' + startingAccountValues);
console.log('endingAccountValues is ' + endingAccountValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` & `filter`. `filter` to get an array without `null`. Then use `array[0]` to get the first element and `array[array.length-1]` to get the last element

```js
//Put all the arrys in an array
var arryArrys = [
  [140, 290, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [110, 130, 120, 140, null, null, null, null],
  [270, 390, 230, null, null, null, null, null]
]

var startVal = 0;
var endVal = 0;
/iterate using forEach
arryArrys.forEach(function(item) {
  // filter elements which are not null
  let intArry = item.filter(function(el) {
    return el !== null

  });
  // add the value to the initial variables
  startVal += intArry[0];
  endVal += intArry[intArry.length - 1];


});
console.log(startVal, endVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function getAccountValues(array) {

  let startingAccountValues = 0,
    endingAccountValues = 0;

  array.forEach(arr => {
    let filteredArr = arr.filter(e => {
      return e !== null;
    });

    startingAccountValues += filteredArr[0];
    endingAccountValues += filteredArr[filteredArr.length - 1];
  })

  return {
    startingAccountValues: startingAccountValues,
    endingAccountValues: endingAccountValues
  }
}

var workArray = [
  [140, 290, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [110, 130, 120, 140, null, null, null, null],
  [270, 390, 230, null, null, null, null, null]
];

console.log(getAccountValues(workArray));
```

As a bonus, you can edit the `workArray` and make it dynamic, not limiting yourself to just 3 arrays!

Answer (score 0):

I will like to use lodash

```
var all =[ [140,290,null,null,null,null,null,null],
[110,130,120,140,null,null,null,null],
[270,390,230,null,null,null,null,null] ];

var firstAmount = 0;
var lastAmount = 0;

_.each(all, function(element) {  
 var nonullElement = _.without(element, null);
 firstAmount += _.head(nonullElement);
 lastAmount += _.nth(nonullElement, -1);
});
```

Comment: It's pretty cool, but your example is like 500 bytes of your code and 50 thousands bytes of library code. There's 10000% of what's necessary.

Answer (score -1):

This should work :)

```js
let arr = [110,130,120,140,null,null,null,null,666]

const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');

arr = arr.filter((item) => item !== null );

appDiv.innerHTML = arr;


appDiv.innerHTML += `<h1>First:${arr[0]}</h1>`;


appDiv.innerHTML += `<h1>Last:${arr[arr.length - 1]}</h1>`;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```